# Rails i18n - how to get all translations for a key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have my translations organized in the normal fashion:

```
en:
  foo:
    bar: 'hello friend'
es:
  foo:
    bar: 'hola amigo'
```

I need to return a hash of all translations for a given key, with the language as the key of the hash, like this:

```
# translations for foo.bar
{
  en: 'hello friend',
  es: 'hola amigo'
}
```

How can I pull that from the i18n engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `I18n` to pull all translations for a given key:

```
key = 'hello'
I18n.available_locales.reduce({}) do |acc, locale|
  acc[locale] = I18n.with_locale(locale) { I18n.t(key) }; acc
end
```

Comment: We were answering at the same time.  Yours works too.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, in case anyone is interested.  Might not be the most efficient way to solve the problem, but this does it:

```
Hash[
  I18n.available_locales.map{|locale|
    [locale, I18n.translate('foo.bar', default: '', locale: locale)]
  }
]
```